# how to convert types of two variables simultaneously?

Tags: r

I have a list of data frames with variables `date` and `temp`. Some variables are `character` type and I'm trying to convert them to the right types

**example data:**

```
library(tidyr)

A <- tibble(date = c("10/01/2020", "11/25/2020", "04/05/2020", "12/14/2020"),
            temp = c("67.28", "52.15", "75.24", "32.14")
            )
B <- tibble(date = as.POSIXct(c("03/01/2020", "7/06/2020", "05/05/2020"), format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
            temp = c("50.37", "88.19", "65.42")
            )
C <- tibble(date = c("02/17/2020", "03/25/2020", "06/18/2020"),
            temp = c(25.86, 49.26, 82.15)
            )

df_list <- list(A, B, C) %>% setNames(c("A", "B", "C"))
```

I want the variable `date` in each data frame to be `Date` type and variable `temp` to be `numeric`. I used `purrr::map` to do the task. However, for some data frames the types aren't changing. For example, `A$temp` and `B$temp` are `character`. I would like them to be `numeric` instead. I think the issue is the `return` statements are forcing the `map` function to exit the loop? Could you help me fix this?

Also I'm using `names(df_list)` to loop each data frames now but I'm quite sure there are cleverer ways to loop the data frames. Any suggestions for improvements will be much appreciated!

**code:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

names(df_list) %>% map(
  function(x){
    if (is.character(df_list[[x]]$date)) return(df_list[[x]] %>% mutate(date = as.Date(date, "%m/%d/%Y")))
    else return(df_list[[x]] %>% mutate(date = as.Date(date)))
    if (is.character(df_list[[x]]$temp)) return(df_list[[x]] %>% mutate(temp = as.numeric(temp)))
    else return(df_list[[x]])
  }
)

[[1]]
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  date       temp 
  <date>     <chr>
1 2020-10-01 67.28
2 2020-11-25 52.15
3 2020-04-05 75.24
4 2020-12-14 32.14

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  date       temp 
  <date>     <chr>
1 2020-03-01 50.37
2 2020-07-06 88.19
3 2020-05-05 65.42

[[3]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  date        temp
  <date>     <dbl>
1 2020-02-17  25.9
2 2020-03-25  49.3
3 2020-06-18  82.2
```

#### EDIT:

I tried removing the `return` statements and now the dates are not changing.

```
names(df_list) %>% map(
  function(x){
    if (is.character(df_list[[x]]$date)) df_list[[x]] %>% mutate(date = as.Date(date, "%m/%d/%Y"))
    else df_list[[x]] %>% mutate(date = as.Date(date))
    if (is.character(df_list[[x]]$temp)) df_list[[x]] %>% mutate(temp = as.numeric(temp))
    else df_list[[x]]
  }
)

[[1]]
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  date        temp
  <chr>      <dbl>
1 10/01/2020  67.3
2 11/25/2020  52.2
3 04/05/2020  75.2
4 12/14/2020  32.1

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  date                 temp
  <dttm>              <dbl>
1 2020-03-01 00:00:00  50.4
2 2020-07-06 00:00:00  88.2
3 2020-05-05 00:00:00  65.4

[[3]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  date        temp
  <chr>      <dbl>
1 02/17/2020  25.9
2 03/25/2020  49.3
3 06/18/2020  82.2
```

Comment: You are creating a private function and values are only changed within that scope. Function will not normally modify values outside their scope. You need to actually save the results somewhere if you want to preserve the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is `tidyverse` solution useing `map`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df_list %>% 
  map(~ mutate(., 
               date = if(is.character(date)) as.Date(date, format="%m/%d/%Y") else as.Date(date), 
               temp = as.numeric(temp)))


$A
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  date        temp
  <date>     <dbl>
1 2020-10-01  67.3
2 2020-11-25  52.2
3 2020-04-05  75.2
4 2020-12-14  32.1

$B
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  date        temp
  <date>     <dbl>
1 2020-02-29  50.4
2 2020-07-05  88.2
3 2020-05-04  65.4

$C
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  date        temp
  <date>     <dbl>
1 2020-02-17  25.9
2 2020-03-25  49.3
3 2020-06-18  82.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all the date columns are to be converted to Date class and all the temp columns to numeric use lapply/transform as shown.  No packages are used.  (It will also work if lapply is replaced with map and transform with mutate.)

```
lapply(df_list, transform, 
  date = as.Date(date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"), 
  temp = as.numeric(temp))
```

giving:

```
$A
        date  temp
1 2020-10-01 67.28
2 2020-11-25 52.15
3 2020-04-05 75.24
4 2020-12-14 32.14

$B
        date  temp
1 2020-03-01 50.37
2 2020-07-06 88.19
3 2020-05-05 65.42

$C
        date  temp
1 2020-02-17 25.86
2 2020-03-25 49.26
3 2020-06-18 82.15
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
df_list |>
  purrr::map(
    function(df) {
      if(is.character(df$date)) df$date <- lubridate::mdy(df$date)
      if("POSIXt" %in% class(df$date)) df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
      if(is.character(df$temp)) df$temp <- as.numeric(df$temp)
      df
    }
  )
```